# Elasticsearch Indexing performance tuning

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, performance-testing, flume

I am loading data into a two node elasticsearch cluster, 5 shards each, using apache-flume (one flume agent) using ExecSource (cat command), file channel and a sink that is custom built using elasticsearch Bulk and XContentBuilder java apis.

The collection of events in flume happens at a rate of 8000 events/sec (size of 1 event 246 bytes) but during indexing in elasticsearch, it gets reduced to 3000 events/sec.

How can I tune indexing performance of elasticsearch to get my throughput close to the rate of collection in flume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written a script which you can download [here](https://gist.github.com/NSmeef/10137239). Its a shell script however I'm sure you can translate irrespective of your platform. There are many variable in indexing performance. Hardware and system variables. There are quite a lot of resources out there.

Comment: Thank you! Managed to enhance throughput to a level almost equal to the rate of collection.

Comment: @Nate Could you please share the script for me? The link is not accessible now.

Comment: @user703555 please hold on for a moment. Appears the page has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider looking at the way logstash writes to elasticsearch - specifically they set the indexing interval to 5s in order to speed up performance. You may also want to test whether compression helps or hinders.

Otherwise, I would increase your cluster size.

Answer (score 0):

use memory channel instead of file channel,it will improve several times output speed.

Comment: I ve tried using memory channel and found that speed increased exponentially. But durability was tremendously hampered. Not only do I lose records when I kill the agent, the ingestion of data was also clumsily inconsistent with some records getting missed out. Thanks though.